# Installation api object detection

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I install api object detection, it's take a lot of space, please tell me which files to save for just detect objects on images, Thanks you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `utils`, `protoc`, and `ipynb script`

```
import numpy as np
import os
import six.moves.urllib as urllib
import sys
import tarfile
import tensorflow as tf
import zipfile

from distutils.version import StrictVersion
from collections import defaultdict
from io import StringIO
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image

from utils import label_map_util

from utils import visualization_utils as vis_util
```

You can see this clearly from the https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb script that is on official repo. Install all the required libraries `NumPy`, `os`, `etc` .. and copy the `utils` directory